# Converting fractions to decimals in Pari/GP

Tags: c, pari

I am using Pari/GP, and I'm getting annoyed by this compilers priority to always represent rational numbers as fractions--rather than giving me a decimal output. And I'd like to know how I can turn a rational number into a decimal expression.

This has started to piss me off, because it should be easier than I am making it. I am dealing with very large fractions `p/q` where `p` and `q` are integers. They each hold about 100 digits of data. Using fractions is ugly as hell in this scenario--picture a 100 digits divided by a 100 digits. I would like to see this fraction as `p/q = a_n...a_1.b_1b_2....b_m`. I want to write the rational fraction in decimal format. I don't care that I lose data; this is irrelevant to my work. I just want to visualize the data better.

I know there's probably some command I am totally overlooking. This is probably a very stupid question. But! For god's sake, somebody help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PARI/GP has built-in numeric types `t_FRAC` for fractions and `t_REAL` for reals. Please, see the example:

```
? type(3/4)
%1 = "t_FRAC"
? 3/4
%2 = 3/4

? type(3/4.0)
%3 = "t_REAL"
? (3/4)*1.0
%4 = 0.75000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

PARI/GP already displays the reals in format you want. The only thing you need to do is to multiply by `1.0` your rationals to cast them to reals.

Also you can control the number of significant digits for reals by setting `realprecision` to the target count.

```
? default(realprecision, 1)
? (3/4)*1.0
%1 = 0.8

? default(realprecision, 5)
? (3/4)*1.0
%2 = 0.75000
```

Comment: Yes, I know real precision and all that. I never would've thought it's just that hacky though; really? I kept on looking for something like "convert t_FRAC to t_REAL"; or some sort of "decimal()" type function. Okay, this is awesome! You've helped me before! Thanks again! I knew it was something super stupid and simple! I'm just going to add a function ```decimal(p) = {return(p*1.0);}```

Comment: Note that you can simply write your function as `decimal(p) = p * 1.0;`

Answer (score 0):

Besides coercing your fractional number to a float (`q * 1.0`, which annoyingly depends on the global parameter`realprecision`), you can also use `printf` with standard C semantics:

```
          ? q = 300000000000/13;
          ? printf("%f", q) \\ use 'realprecision' for conversion
          23076923076.923076923076923076923076923
          ? printf("%e", q)   
          2.3076923076923076923076923076923076923 e10
          ? printf(".3e", q)  \\ 3 digits after decimal point
          2.308 e10
```

(see `??printf` for lots of options). You can also use `Strprintf` (same options) to convert from rational instead of printing.